# Can't load assembly at runtime

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, assemblies

I'm working with a 3rd party assembly to implement something in our in-house software. I can make the refence and work with the library without a problem, but when I run the program to test it i'm getting this error

"Can't load file or assembly "assembly file" nor either of its dependencies. The system couldn't find the specified file" (i'm from Mexico, exception is in Spanish so i had to tanslate it, sorry for the poor translation)

I have given read and write permission to the file, the folder, and for all users and still wont load it.

I saw that the assembly has the PublicKeyToken=null, does that have any to do with that i cant load the assembly????

I already asked the people who developes this assembly, but i'm not getting any response and I really wanna get this project finished

Comment: Have you tried placing the assembly in the same folder with the executable?...or if it's a signed assembly...in the GAC folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> The Assembly Binding Log Viewer displays details for assembly binds. This information helps you diagnose why the .NET Framework cannot locate an assembly at run time.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, i used and found out the assembly was looking for BanortePinPad.dll and my dll was name BanortePinPad Net.dll. Just had to remove the %20Net and worked. The sad thing is the developer of the Dll didnt knew what the problem was, xD

Answer (score 2):

If this is a web application, is the DLL in the bin folder? If it is a deskop application, is it in the same directory as the executable? If not, you may need to set the "Copy Local" attribute on the dll to true in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Plus to what Chris said, you have to ensure that if the 3rd party dlls need any other dlls then they must be also in the bin directory, (you can check this by looking at the original directory of the 3rd party dlls and copy all dlls that come with it)